# Soft body simulation to 3D print

Tags: 3d-printing, soft-body

I have a soft body simulation that is about 20 frames long. I'd like to pick a specific frame and "fix" the geometry in place so that I can export the distorted model out for 3D printing. I'm new to Blender, and all I can seem to find is references to baking (which I don't think is exactly what I'm looking for). Every time I switch to edit mode, the simulation just pops back to the original, non-distorted geometry. Thoughts?

Comment: Get to the frame where it's how you want, then "apply" the soft body modifier, from the drop-down menu on the modifier to the right of the modifier's name.

Comment: Of course! I didn't realize that soft bodies were modifiers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is correct, but in case anyone else stumbles across this question, here's the answer:

1. Go to the frame you want
2. Apply the soft-body body modifier